# Adding custom property or replacing read-only property

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to automate a loop that goes through our servers collecting logs from eventviewer to later export into a webpage which works just fine, BUT, I would like to add a property to this list or possible modify an existing read-only property.

Here is the scriptlines I'm using:

```
$eventlog = (Get-EventLog -LogName system -Newest 5 -EntryType Error)
$eventlog | Select-Object Source,Message,MachineName | ConvertTo-Html -Head $a | Out-File C:\logs.htm
```

The only real issue here is that the property "MachineName" list "name.domain.com" instead of just "name", so I went ahead and added the following:

```
$eventlog | ForEach-Object {
$_.MachineName=$env:COMPUTERNAME
}
```

This was stopped because the property is read-only so I thought I could perhaps add a property to my object and just populate it with a variable which I still believe should work but I'm not getting the hang of how `Add-Member`works fully.
Here is how I went about it:

```
$eventlog | Add-Member -Name Hostname -Value $env:COMPUTERNAME
```

or

```
Add-Member -InputObject $eventlog -Name Hostname -Value $env:COMPUTERNAME
```

Obviously this alone doesn't work but I can't get my head around how the rest of the parameters are supposed to look. I'm also fairly certain the line above isn't even right but it's enough to make you understand what I'm trying to achieve and perhaps know of a better solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a *calculated property*. This way you can modify read only properties or add new....

```
$eventlog = (Get-EventLog -LogName system -Newest 5 -EntryType Error)
$eventlog | Select-Object Source,Message, @{l='MachineName'; e={$env:COMPUTERNAME}} | 
    ConvertTo-Html -Head $a | 
    Out-File C:\logs.htm
```

Comment: Thank you a thousand times! That is perfect, it's short and simple that is easy to understand!

Answer (score 1):

```
$eventlog | Add-Member -Name 'Hostname' -Value $env:COMPUTERNAME -MemberType NoteProperty
$eventlog | Select ...,hostname | ConvertTo-Html -Head $a | Out-File C:\logs.htm
```

Comment: Thanks 4c7, Looks like I was on the right track, didn't understand the "NoteProperty" though on my own!

Comment: ;) but Martin's answer is better ;) I was just thinking how to achieve it your way ;)